# path_hierarchy in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to use the path_hierarchy tokenizer with paths that have whitespace in them and have it create tokens based only on the delimiter not the whitespace? For example,

"/airport/hangar 1"

would be tokenized as

"airport", "hangar 1",

not

"airport", "hangar", "1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path_hierarchy tokenizer works perfectly fine with paths that have whitespaces:

```
curl "localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=path_hierarchy&pretty=true" -d "/airport/hangar 1"
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "/airport",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 8,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "/airport/hangar 1",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 17,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

However, based on your example, you might need to use the [pattern](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/pattern-tokenizer.html) tokenizer instead.

Comment: arrgh...can't post code in a comment. My mapping must be messed up. I'm going to try to put it in a gist so you can see it. I have this in my mapping: https://gist.github.com/fourlincoln10/5230450. When I run _analyze against the field categories.path I get three tokens: airport, hangar, 1?

Comment: Think I figured it out...I was querying the wrong field. categories is nested in a nested attribute type, so I had to query attributes.categories.path...thanks for your help.